# STL: set_union, includes, mismatch, find_if but is there no includes_any?

Tags: c++, stl

From the title you'd almost assuredly think use `set_union` to create a `list` and then check if it's empty.  However, the objects I'm comparing are "expensive" to copy.  I've looked at `includes` but that only works if *all* the items of one list are found in another.  I've also looked at `mismatch` but rejected it for obvious reasons.

I can and have written my own function which assumes both lists are sorted but I'm wondering if an efficient function already exists in the STL.  (Project is forbidden to use third-party libraries including Boost and TR1, don't ask.)

Comment: `set_union` probably wouldn't work anyway. The union of two sets is the combination of elements that appear in either set, so you'd never get an empty list unless both input lists were empty. You were probably thinking of `set_intersection`.

Comment: @Michael Madsen - yes, you're right.  In my head I knew what I meant, on paper it came out entirely different.  Funny how that happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the sets are unsorted, then you can use `find_first_of` for an O(N*M) algorithm.

If they are sorted (which would be required for `set_intersection` anyway), then you can iterate over one set calling `equal_range` in the other for every element. If every returned range is empty, there is no intersection. Performance is O(N log M).

However, there is no excuse not to have O(N+M) performance, right? Nothing is copied by `set_intersection` if it's passed a dummy iterator.

```
struct found {};

template< class T > // satisfy language requirement
struct throwing_iterator : std::iterator< std::output_iterator_tag, T > {
    T &operator*() { throw found(); }
    throwing_iterator &operator++() { return *this; }
    throwing_iterator operator++(int) { return *this; }
};

template< class I, class J >
bool any_intersection( I first1, I last1, J first2, J last2 ) {
    try {
        throwing_iterator< typename std::iterator_traits<I>::value_type > ti;
        set_intersection( first1, last1, first2, last2, ti );
        return false;
    } catch ( found const& ) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

This provides for early exit. You could alternately avoid the exception and just have the iterator remember how many times it was incremented, and no-op the assignment.

Comment: `equal_range` only takes a single element (or predicate) so, I'm not sure how you mean it should be used in paragraph two. I like the use of `set_intersection`, though.

Comment: @Charles: The same way `find_first_of` works: by iterating over one set.

Comment: `find_first_of` takes two ranges so it's one call. I may just be being slow but what does `equal_range` give you that, say, `find` doesn't given that you'll have to do some sort of loop?

Comment: @Charles: `equal_range` works on a sorted sequence and is O(log N). `find` works on unsorted and is O(N). Clarified answer.

Comment: True, I only meant from the complexity of the required supporting code. OK, what advantage over, say, `binary_search`?

Comment: @Charles: I forgot about `binary_search`, lol. All it does is compare the `first` and `second` of `equal_range`'s result, which is what's needed here.

Comment: OK, post-edit, I think I'm with you. You did mean that you need to iterate over one set searching in the other.

Comment: This is nice, didn't even think to give a dummy type iterator.  I don't like that you're using an exception to do unexceptional behavior but all in all I think it's terrific.

Comment: @wheaties: you'll have to decide whether the likely performance benefit of an early-exit (in the case where the intersection is non-empty) is worth the argument over what exceptions "are for". If it helps I suppose you could argue that "I don't want this algorithm to run to completion" is an exceptional circumstance from the POV of the algorithm, if not from the POV of the caller (hence you catch it - any exception caught and not rethrown can't be all that "exceptional" from the POV of the catcher). Or you could just copy-paste-modify your implementation of `set_intersection`.

Answer (score 1):

Is `find_first_of()` what you're after?

Comment: @wheaties: This is why I love http://cplusplus.com, where I got the answer from...!

Comment: Lol, yes but it's still an operation of M*N, with ordering I thought there might be a snazzier function.  Oh well.  Rather use STL than roll my own.